# Getting errors after install linux when i tried to open my vue 3 project

Tags: vuejs3, node-modules

whenever i try to open any of my vue 3 project. I tried npm i autoprefixer but didn't work , then i tried deleting packagelock.json and node modules also it's not working, below are the errors I receive :

Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/router/index.js 4:0-51

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../views/AccountView.vue' in 'D:\project\Church\src\router'

ERROR in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7ba5bd90&lang=css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-12.use[1]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-12.use[2]!./node_modules/vue-cli-plugin-quasar/lib/loader.vue.auto-import-quasar.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[1]!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7ba5bd90&lang=css)

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'
Require stack:

- D:\project.postcssrc.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\loaders.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\ExplorerBase.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\Explorer.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\index.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\utils.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\index.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\cjs.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\progress-webpack-plugin\index.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\commands\serve.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object. (D:\project.postcssrc.js:2:3)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
  at module.exports (D:\project\Church\node_modules\import-fresh\index.js:32:59)
  at loadJs (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\loaders.js:16:18)
  at Explorer.loadFileContent (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\Explorer.js:84:32)
  at Explorer.createCosmiconfigResult (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\Explorer.js:89:36)
  at Explorer.loadSearchPlace (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\Explorer.js:70:31)
  at async Explorer.searchDirectory (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\Explorer.js:55:27)
  at async run (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\Explorer.js:35:22)
  at async cacheWrapper (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\cacheWrapper.js:16:18)
  at async cacheWrapper (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\cacheWrapper.js:16:18)
  at async cacheWrapper (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\cacheWrapper.js:16:18)
  at async Explorer.search (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\Explorer.js:27:20)
  at async loadConfig (D:\project\Church\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\utils.js:68:16)
  at async Object.loader (D:\project\Church\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\index.js:54:22)

ERROR in ./node_modules/@quasar/extras/material-icons/material-icons.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-14.use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-14.use[2]!./node_modules/@quasar/extras/material-icons/material-icons.css)

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'
Require stack:

- D:\project.postcssrc.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\loaders.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\ExplorerBase.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\Explorer.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\index.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\utils.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\index.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\cjs.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\progress-webpack-plugin\index.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\commands\serve.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object. (D:\project.postcssrc.js:2:3)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
  at module.exports (D:\project\Church\node_modules\import-fresh\index.js:32:59)
  at loadJs (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\loaders.js:16:18)
  at Explorer.loadFileContent (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\Explorer.js:84:32)
  at Explorer.createCosmiconfigResult (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\Explorer.js:89:36)
  at Explorer.loadSearchPlace (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\Explorer.js:70:31)
  at async Explorer.searchDirectory (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\Explorer.js:55:27)
  at async run (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\Explorer.js:35:22)
  at async cacheWrapper (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\cacheWrapper.js:16:18)
  at async cacheWrapper (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\cacheWrapper.js:16:18)
  at async cacheWrapper (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\cacheWrapper.js:16:18)
  at async cacheWrapper (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\cacheWrapper.js:16:18)
  at async cacheWrapper (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\cacheWrapper.js:16:18)
  at async cacheWrapper (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\cacheWrapper.js:16:18)
  at async Explorer.search (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\Explorer.js:27:20)
  at async loadConfig (D:\project\Church\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\utils.js:68:16)
  at async Object.loader (D:\project\Church\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\index.js:54:22)

ERROR in ./src/styles/quasar.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-24.use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-24.use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-24.use[3]!./node_modules/vue-cli-plugin-quasar/lib/loader.scss.js!./src/styles/quasar.scss)

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'
Require stack:

- D:\project.postcssrc.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\loaders.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\ExplorerBase.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\Explorer.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\index.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\utils.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\index.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\cjs.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules\progress-webpack-plugin\index.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\commands\serve.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js
- D:\project\Church\node_modules@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object. (D:\project.postcssrc.js:2:3)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
  at module.exports (D:\project\Church\node_modules\import-fresh\index.js:32:59)
  at loadJs (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\loaders.js:16:18)
  at Explorer.loadFileContent (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\Explorer.js:84:32)
  at Explorer.createCosmiconfigResult (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\Explorer.js:89:36)
  at Explorer.loadSearchPlace (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\Explorer.js:70:31)
  at async Explorer.searchDirectory (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\Explorer.js:55:27)
  at async run (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\Explorer.js:35:22)
  at async cacheWrapper (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\cacheWrapper.js:16:18)
  at async cacheWrapper (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\cacheWrapper.js:16:18)
  at async cacheWrapper (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\cacheWrapper.js:16:18)
  at async cacheWrapper (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\cacheWrapper.js:16:18)
  at async Explorer.search (D:\project\Church\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist\Explorer.js:27:20)
  at async loadConfig (D:\project\Church\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\utils.js:68:16)
  at async Object.loader (D:\project\Church\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\index.js:54:22)

Comment: @IVO GELOV I tried but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You should run `npm install -D autoprefixer` and then make sure that the file `src/router/views/AccountView.vue` does exist. IF it does not exist there - you must update the pathname in `src/router/index.js`